# char array contains garbage at the end

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So, I wrote the following function in C:

```
void splitNameAndDate(char *p, char *n, char *d) {
    int d_index = 0, n_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(p); i++) {
        if(p[i] >= '0' && p[i] <= '9') {
            d[date_index++] = p[i];
        } else {
            n[name_index++] = p[i];
        }
    }
}
```

This function gets an array (representing a person) which looks like this: `adam1502` (name and date) and splits it into two arrays - name and date. I initialize the arrays like this:

`char date[5],name[50],person[50];`

If for example `p` array has `Michelle1001`, then `n` array, for some reason, has `Michelle\023`. Can't understand why it puts `\023` a the end. Other tests work fine, though.

P.S I use the debugger of Clion to see what the array contains.

** EDIT - can I use the following code at the end?

```
date[date_index] = '\0';
name[name_index] = '\0';
```

Comment: How did you initialize the array?

Comment: 23rd entry in the ASCII table is end-of-block

Comment: The string pointed to by `d` remains unterminated because nobody bothered to terminate it. Run the code by hand assuming that initially `d` points to `\x1F` `\x20` `\x21` `\x22` `\x23`.

Comment: You forgot to zero-terminate the strings.   So yes, the "EDIT" is required.

Comment: @HansPassant Can I initialize from the start like this?: `name[50] = '\0'` The IDE warns me `Compound array initializer is expected`

Comment: Sure, the compound initializer you want looks like name[50] = {};  Which sets all of the elements to 0.  Not much point to it when you also do it the fast way, you need only one 0.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're hit by indeterminate values.

A local scope definition like

```
  char date[5],name[50],person[50];
```

leave all the members of the array uninitialized, hence the values are indeterminate.

Later, you only copy the relevant values upto a certain index (minus the null-terminator), the remaining values are still left at indeterminate. So, you can see some arbitary value there.

Comment: Yeah that what I though (altough other tests worked fine). how I should treat this situation?

Comment: @vesii that depends. If you want to see any specific value, be easiest is to zero initialize the arrays, It'll help you in null-termination, also.